# Нужно ли выделять деепричастие?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастия

Нужно ли выделять деепричастие "кусая": Если дрессировать свою совесть, то и кусая она будет целовать нас?

Answer (score 3):

Если дрессировать свою совесть, то и кусая, она будет целовать нас.

И - усилительная частица, её нельзя отделять от деепричастия. Если бы деепричастие стояло в конце предложения, можно было бы не обособлять вообще: *Если дрессировать свою совесть, то  она будет целовать нас и кусая* - деепричастие составляет единое целое со сказуемым. У нас стоит впереди, обособлять надо.

Кстати, у Ницше  запятая есть: [http://sdamzavas.net/3-43821.htmlНицше](http://sdamzavas.net/3-43821.html%D0%9D%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%88%D0%B5) Ф. По ту сторону добра и зла //Избранные произведения. В 4 - х т. Т. 2. – Л. : Ступени, 1994. – С. 270–272, 294–296, 26–327.

Comment: По вашей ссылке я этого афоризма не нашел. А вот здесь запятой нет: lib.ru/NICSHE/dobro_i_zlo.txt_with-big-pictures.html. Впрочем, это всего лишь перевод...

Answer (score 2):

Если дрессировать свою совесть, **то и кусАя,** она будет целовАть нас.

1) **Розенталь  об усилительной частице И**: [деепричастные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113)

Одиночное деепричастие или деепричастный оборот не обособляется: 3) если перед деепричастным оборотом стоит **усилительная частица и:** Можно прожить **и не хвастая умом** (М. Г.); Можете уйти **и не дожидаясь ответа**; Он оставался скромным **и победив** сильного противника.

2) Мы должны хорошо помнить это свойство частицы И, но тогда почему мы здесь, нимало не сомневаясь, о**бособляем оборот  "и кусая"?** Конечно же всё дело **в структуре предложения**: при инверсии (препозиции оборота)  **правило с частицей И не действует**, причем именно это правило.

3) В принципе **деепричастие может не обособляться в любой позиции**, в том числе в начале и в середине предложения, но при этом оно должно вписываться в **структуру предложения,** занимая позицию наречия. Например (у Розенталя): Он **не считая** бросал деньги. **Не торопясь** он прошёлся по комнате. **Не задумываясь** отвергла она.

4) В нашем же случае  инверсированный оборот в структуру предложения **явно не вписывается и без обособления не читается:** требуется пауза и два фразовых (тонических, логических) ударения.

Comment: А в печатных изданиях запятой нет.  Например: lib.ru/NICSHE/dobro_i_zlo.txt_with-big-pictures.html. Фридрих Ницше, сочинения в 2-х томах, том 2, издательство "Мысль", Москва 1990

Comment: Спасибо, интересное замечание. Значит, возможны два решения. Тогда при отсутствии запятой  логически выделяется  только деепричастие, пауза отсутствует: "...то и кусАя она будет целовать нас". Семантика отчасти меняется, я понимаю это примерно так. .(1) Хотя это  не очень хороший поступок,  но ты все равно молодец. (2) Это не очень хороший поступок,  но ты все равно молодец.